# What is the notation for calculating the mode?

Tags: notation

#### Question:

What is appropriate notation for calculating the mode of a function? In this case, I use the mode of a Gamma(a,b) distribution in a cost-function.

I am looking for something analogous to $\bar{x}$ or $\tilde{x}$ notation that is commonly used for the mean and medians, respectively, if something like $\bar{\text{G}(a,b)}$ would make sense.

#### What I have tried:

1. Google results are confounded by mode $\simeq$ model and results for latex's 'math mode'
2. It is not on the following wikipedia pages:

   - [Greek letters used in mathematics, science, and engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_letters_used_in_mathematics,_science,_and_engineering)
   - [Table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols)
   - [Latin letters used in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_letters_used_in_mathematics)

Comment: For 1: [tried this](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22mode%22+%22gamma%2Bdistribution%22)?

Comment: @J.M. that gives the analytical form of the mode, but that is not what I want. I have changed my question to focus on notation for mode rather than calculation of the mode of the gamma.

Comment: I was addressing the "Google results are confounded by" portion in #1; that is, use quote marks to tell Google that you meant what you said.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the hint. But I am still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility for the notation for a mode is $$\underset{x}{\operatorname{arg\,max}} f(x)$$ but I thought that was ugly, so [here](http://www.se16.info/hgb/mode.pdf) I used a hat $$\hat{X}$$ to indicate the peak in the probability density or mass function, even though this can also be used for other meanings.

Comment: Note: This can also be written simply as $\operatorname{argmax} f$.

Answer (score 1):

In Bayesian estimation, the mode is given by the [maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation). Using the "MAP" subscript would suffice.

Comment: .. except that I am not using a posterior, I am using data to set the mode of an informed Gamma prior.

Comment: @David: I would just pick a symbol and explain it.

Comment: thanks ... right now I am using mode(G(a,b)); perhaps I could use $u()$ but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel